# Rebuilding Domain From Scratch. How to Use Old Netbios Domain Name on new DC?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller, netbios

I have a client that I am currently in the process of upgrading from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012R2. They are a small business, working off of a single server. The decision was made to rebuild their entire domain from the ground-up rather than joining the new DC to the old domain and promoting it. This is fine for the most part, but I'd like to be able to reuse the same netbios domain name. This is how it breaks down at the moment:

2003 Server (production)

**Netbios**: example

**Domain**: example.lc

2012R2 Server (being provisioned)

**Netbios**: example0

**Domain**: example.local

And my goal (hopefully) would be to make it so that the new server ends up with the Netbios "Example" rather than "Example0", which it currently has. Any suggestions? Is this possible?

Comment: Disconnect the new DC from the existing AD network and name it accordingly. You don't need to name it `example0` and doing so would necessitate a domain rename to make it `example`.

Comment: Problem being that there is only one network at this client and I need to migrate several hundred gigabytes of shared files, and a database to the new DC, so they have to be able to communicate with each other. Would it be possible for both DC's to have the same netbios simultaneously?

Comment: No it isn't. Why not transfer the data before making the new server a DC? Additionally, why not transfer the data via an external USB drive?

Comment: I think that could work. Could another possibility be to do the DC move and then change the netbios name to "example" after the fact?

Comment: What do you mean `do the DC move`? Do you mean rename it after you've joined the clients to the new domain?

Comment: Exactly. Is that something that is doable?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know why you'd want to do that. You'd have to touch every client if you rename the domain after you join the clients to it.